# What is Zero Dynamics of a system?

Tags: control-system, pole-zeroplot, dynamic

I am trying to understand Zero Dynamic attack(ZDA) on a system, but for that I am confused what exactly is ‘’’Zero dynamics of a system’’’.

Is it the state of a system at one of its zeroes or something else and how it is related to ZDA on a system.

Comment: If the system has a zero, it means there's some form of input that is not visible in the output. If you excite with this input, you can still affect the states of the system, potentially in a dangerous way.

Comment: @FredrikBagge so "Zero Dynamics" refers to the control action or input to the system when the output is zero. And if we use this input we will affect the state but there will be no output? Am I understanding it correctly?